# Method [validate1504030121.jpeg] does not exist

Tags: laravel, validation

(1/1) BadMethodCallException

Method [validate1504030121.jpeg] does not exist.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
    if( $request->hasfile('thumbnail') && $request->thumbnail->isvalid())
    {
      $extension = $request->thumbnail->extension();
      $filename = time()."-.".$extension;

      $request->thumbnail->move(public_path('image'), $filename);
    }else
    {
      $fileiname = 'sagewolf.png';
    }


    //print_r($request->all());
  $this->validate($request, [
    'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
    'body' => 'required',
    'user_id'=> 'required',
    'catagory'=>'required',
    'thumbnail'=>$filename, ]);
    $store = Post::create($request->all());
```

Want to avoid thumbnail field from validation rules.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think more context might be required.

Comment: more context added.

Comment: go ahead and answer your own question then.